# Updating label twice and calling sleep() in between -- only second update is seen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obj-C -> Incrementing a number (and showing steps on a Cocoa label)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237621/obj-c-incrementing-a-number-and-showing-steps-on-a-cocoa-label)

I'm wondering why this isn´t working: the sleep and "whatever" is showing up as expected, but not the `NSString` before the sleep function (computing...). The label is empty for 1 second and then the second string shows up. Why is that?

```
if ([label.text isEqualToString : @"1"]) {
    [label2 setText : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"Computing..."]];
    sleep (1);
    [label2 setText : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"Whatever"]];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obj-C -> Incrementing a number (and showing steps on a Cocoa label)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237621/obj-c-incrementing-a-number-and-showing-steps-on-a-cocoa-label), [Loop to change label text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325202/), [Text field waits until the end of a loop to update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829977/), and especially [Calling sleep() and updating text field not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834062/calling-sleep5-and-updating-text-field-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

This is presumably taking place on the main thread. By sleeping, you stop the screen from updating and so the first change is not displayed. Then as soon as the thread resumes, you change the text again, causing it to appear as if the text was never set before.

Edit:
If you want to fix it, the easiest way is to change the sleep call and the second `-setText:` to be just `[label2 performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Whatever"] afterDelay:1.0];`.

Comment: It´s taking place in an Instance method (IBAction) user touches a button. I thought that the compiler reads "top to down" I don´t know how I would make 1 variable run before the other hmm..

Answer (score 3):

You could call:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

Then have the method updateLabel:

```
[label2 setText:@"Whatever"];
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the actual screen update hasn't occured yet when you call the sleep() function, so when you update the field again immediately after, that's what you end up seeing on screen.

If you really need to make sure the first string appears on screen before the second one, you're going to have to make sure that the display has actually been updated, not just do sleep().